# In Matthew 27:62, what is "the day of preparation"?

Tags: judaism, passover, second-temple-judaism

I investigated this matter at https://judaism.stackexchange.com and I was assured that there is no such Jewish holy day. So to what does the term actually refer?

> [Matthew 27:62 NKJV] (62) On the next day, which followed the Day of Preparation, the chief priests and Pharisees gathered together to Pilate,

I would appreciate both an explanation and a day of Nisan as an answer.

Also, does Matthew clarify "the next day" with "which followed the Day of Preparation" to indicate that he meant the "day" part of the "evening and morning" of the day that Jesus was buried, which was Nisan 14/Pesach, when one would eat the meal? If so, how does he have Jesus observing the Passover feast?

And how does one square that with this?: [Mark 14:12 NASB20] (12) On the first day of Unleavened Bread, when the Passover [lamb] was being sacrificed, His disciples said to Him, "Where do You want us to go and prepare for You to eat the Passover?"

Possibly remotely relevant:

[Does Leviticus 23 Contradict the Rabbinical Sunset Reckoning of Calendar Days?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/45407/does-leviticus-23-contradict-the-rabbinical-sunset-reckoning-of-calendar-days)

Also, the longer reviews for these books are very relevant:

https://www.amazon.com/Jesus-Last-Supper-Brant-Pitre/product-reviews/0802875335/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_paging_btm_next_2?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=2

[https://www.amazon.com/The-Mystery-of-the-Last-Supper-Reconstructing-the-Final-Days-of-Jesus/dp/052173200X/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_rvw_txt?ie=UTF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052173200X)

Comment: Do you mean a date (14th or 15th, etc), as distinct from Friday?

Comment: Hmm.... well I guess if it depends on how the day is reckoned. If evening then morning, then the Nisan day, but if morning to night, the Gregorian day number. Dates are hard!

Comment: The day of preparation for Shabbat is not a holiday. - Pesach (14th of Aviv) & Chag HaMatzot (Festival of Unleavened Bread, 15-21 of Aviv) are the holidays. * Yeshua was arrested on the Eve of Pesach (supposedly) as written in [Sanhedrin 43a:20] https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.43a.20?with=all&lang=bi

Comment: Excellent resource, thanks. Do we know the date of the writing of that? Also, it says that he was hung on the eve of Passover. By that they mean Pesach?

Comment: @Ruminator - Correct. The Sanhedrin claims Yeshua [the Nazarene] was hung after trial on  בערב הפסח "Eve of The Passover" as stated in the Talmud - Sanhedrin 43a : 20.

Comment: The reason I'm seeking confirmation is that in modern times, at least, as I understand it, among Jews, "Passover" refers to the feast of unleavened bread, while "Pesach" refers to the slaughter of the lambs and the meal on Nisan 14.  https://www.aish.com/atr/Passover-14th-or-15th.html?catid=907549

Comment: Pesach פסח "Pass [over]" is only the 14th of Aviv. - After the Babylonian exile, the month "Aviv" was given the Babylonian name Nisan. * Chag HaMatsot (15-21 of Aviv) is sometimes called פסח Pesach "Passover" because it is one continuous feast of Unleavened Bread - [Exodus 12:18 ] - https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.12.18?with=Commentary&lang=bi&aliyot=0

Comment: Okay, thanks @חִידָה.

Comment: Apparently the Mishnah from which the link about the date is from about 500 AD/CE. Still, an interesting report.

Comment: That Sefaria page describes first conviction, then forty days of public announcement, then stoning, and finally hanging up the dead body.  So it's rather hard for anyone who accepts the gospels as inspired to take that page seriously.

Answer (score 4):

The "day of preparation" is neither a holiday nor a holy day.
There is nothing official about it.
Perhaps the biggest cause of confusion is that the translators chose to capitalize it, making it seem like a proper noun.

For the weekly sabbath, and those high holidays that are treated as sabbaths ([High Sabbaths - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Sabbaths#:%7E:text=One%20occurs%20in%20the%20summer,the%20first%20and%20last%20day.)), people must do extra work preparing for the next day when they won't be cooking meals etc. (just as the Israelites in the desert gathered double manna the day before each sabbath).
This is why the day before each sabbath, whether weekly or annual high day, is referred to as a day of preparation.

Consider 2023:

- On Wednesday April 24, during the daytime people prepare food etc. for the annual Passover high holiday and rid their homes of all traces of yeast in preparation for the Days of Unleavened Bread.
  (In ancient times, at around 3 pm, the Passover lambs were slaughtered.)
  In the Hebrew calendar, this is Nisan 14.
- At sunset, the high holiday begins, and the Passover seder is eaten.
- That night, and Thursday daytime are a high holiday, treated as a sabbath, with no work.
- Friday daytime is another day of preparation, albeit a much lesser one, this time for the weekly sabbath, which begins at sunset.
- The weekly sabbath ends when the sun sets on Saturday.
- On Sunday (the first day of the week immediately after the first weekly sabbath during the Days of Unleavened Bread), priests make a wavesheaf offering.
  Starting from that Sunday, 7 weeks are counted until Sunday, 50 days later (Pentecost).

The same thing happened nearly 2000 years ago, in AD 31:

- Tuesday evening, Jesus eats his "Last Supper", which is not the Passover seder, with his disciples.
- Wednesday, the 14<sup>th</sup> of Nisan (25<sup>th</sup> of April), is the day of preparation for the high holiday ("*Therefore, because it was the Preparation Day, that the bodies should not remain on the cross on the Sabbath (for **that Sabbath was a high day**), the Jews asked Pilate that their legs might be broken, and that they might be taken away.*" — John 19:31).
  Jesus is tortured and executed, dying at about 3 pm, and hurriedly buried before sunset (about 6 pm) when the annual sabbath begins.
- That evening the already prepared Passover seder is eaten.
  (A partial lunar eclipse, which can cause the moon to appear red, occurred on Wednesday 25 April in the year 31.)
  Everyone then rests during the high holy day until sunset on Thursday.
- Friday is a normal Friday, the first chance the women have to buy spices ("*And **when the sabbath was past**, [the women] had **bought sweet spices**, that they might come and anoint him.*" — Mark 16:1).
  They prepare the spices during the day on that Friday.
  They then rest when the weekly sabbath begins at sunset.
  ("*[the women] returned and **prepared spices** and fragrant oils. **And they rested on the Sabbath** according to the commandment.*" — Luke 23:56).
  Notice that there are *two* distinct sabbaths, the high sabbath before Friday, and the weekly sabbath after.
- Just before sunset on Saturday, when the sabbath ends, exactly three days and three nights after his burial, Jesus is resurrected ("*For as Jonah was three days and three nights in the belly of the great fish, so will the Son of Man be three days and three nights in the heart of the earth.*" — Matthew 12:40).
- Very early Sunday morning, long before sunrise, the women bring the spices to the tomb and find it empty ("*Now on the first day of the week Mary Magdalene went to the tomb early, **while it was still dark**, and saw that the stone had been taken away from the tomb.*" — John 20:1).
  Matthew 28:1 refers to that Sunday morning as "*In the end of the sabbath …*". Some versions of the Bible translate that as "*After the sabbath**s***" (e.g. LITV, CLNT, YLT, Fenton), the plural confirming that there was more than one sabbath.
  Later that day, the resurrected Jesus becomes God's firstfruit, as had been symbolized by the wavesheaf offering.

Referring to Joel 2:31, Acts 2:20 says "*The sun shall be turned into darkness, and the moon into blood, before that great and notable day of the Lord come*". Apocrypha also refer to a blood-moon on the night of the crucifixion.

On Wednesday 25 April in the year 31, a partial lunar eclipse occurred, causing the moon to appear red.

31 is the only year within a decade in which Passover began on a Wednesday.

I have a crude chart of the events in [Crucifixion/Resurrection Synoptic Time Table](https://rbutterworth.nfshost.com/Tables/crucifixion-resurrection/).

Comment: Thanks. How do you square that with this?: *[Mark 14:12 NASB20] (12) On the first day of Unleavened Bread, when the Passover [lamb] was being sacrificed, His disciples said to Him, "Where do You want us to go and prepare for You to eat the Passover?"*

Comment: @Ruminator, Mark 14:12 as it's commonly translated doesn't make sense.
The lambs aren't slaughtered on the official first Day of Unleavened bread; but the day before.
¶ Mark wrote to a Roman gentile audience, so "*unleavened bread, when they killed the passover*" reminds them of this event.
One day each year when a large number of lambs are slaughtered is very memorable.
"when" refers to the entire time, not to the specific day, just as the Greek word for "day" can refer to a much larger time period.
¶ Similarly "first" could mean the beginning of this period, not the literal first day.

Comment: Exodus 12:18-19 seems to suggest that the feast seemed to include Nisan 14/the Passover meal. (They're trying to drive us all nuts!)

Comment: @Ruminator, I think that "even" means the end of the day while "eve" means the beginning of the night (the transition between days being at sunset). It's like we now say in English, "Xmas Eve" for the night before the 25th, while "Xmas evening" would be the night following the daytime part of the 25th. So "*on the fourteenth day of the month at even*" would mean that on the 14th, when it starts to get dark, is when one switches to unleavened bread. During the day on the 14th, leavened bread is allowed (but I suspect difficult to find).

Comment: This might be helpful:  https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/3343-bitter-herbs#anchor5

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this answers the question, and if not I am happy to delete this answer.

The timing of the crucifixion is clearly demonstrated by the following Gospel references:

**Matthew:**

- Death on Friday (παρασκευή preparation day): Matt 27:57, 62
- Sabbath rest: Matt 27:62-65 (Guard)
- Resurrection on Sunday (first of the week): Matt 28:1, 4 (Notice here that the guard was undisturbed until Sunday morning.  Further, the KJV in Matt 28:1 has an awkward translation that incorrectly implies that the tomb was found empty late on the Sabbath.  Every modern version has it more correctly.)

**Mark:**

- Death on Friday (παρασκευή preparation day): Mark 15:42
- Sabbath rest: -
- Resurrection on Sunday (first of the week): Mark 16:1, 9 (This latter text states unequivocally that Jesus rose on the first day of the week.  The Greek is even clearer!)

**Luke:**

- Death on Friday (preparation day): Luke 23:54
- Sabbath rest: Luke 23:56
- Resurrection on Sunday (first of the week): Luke 24:1-7

**John:**

- Death on Friday (preparation day): John 19:14, 31, 42
- Sabbath rest: -
- Resurrection on Sunday (first of the week): John 20:1, 17

Notice that in all these cases, the day of Jesus’ death is described as the preparation day (παρασκευή paraskeue) – an invariant designator of what we now call Friday, the sixth day of the week.  There is not a single exception to this rule in any literature; in neither the New Testament nor any of the Apostolic Fathers.  This practice is so wide spread that the same word for Friday was also adopted into Latin, Parascue.

This all occurred at the time of the Passover, Matt 26:19, Mark 14:16, Luke 22:15, John 18:39.

Comment: Hi Dottard. Thanks for the response. I know I mentioned hoping to learn the day, but in reality, the more primary question is, since Jews know nothing about a "day of preparation," what might Matthew be referring to that the Jews and the scriptures DO know about?! My guess might be the search for leaven, but I really don't know. The slaughter of the lambs? Maybe?

Comment: @Ruminator - The Jews know nothing about a "day of preparation,"  ?? See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10657/why-dont-we-say-tachanun-at-mincha-on-erev-shabbat-or-erev-yom-tov/18666#18666  Friday for Jews is just the preparation for Sabbath

Comment: @Ruminator - the many Jews I know use Friday as the preparation day for sabbath each week.  It is not a holiday.

Comment: I see the word "preparation" but that is the only link I see with that post, which seems to have to do with mourning for the dead!

Comment: Where in Leviticus 23 is "the day of preparation" described?

Comment: @Ruminator - it is not in Lev 23 - it is not a holy day.  It is simply the day before the weekly sabbath and so was called the preparation day.  See BDAG and Thayer.  Further, the link I sent one of the answers calls Friday the day of preparation.

Comment: To which verse in Leviticus 23 are you referring?

Comment: @Ruminator - as stated above, I am not referring any verse in Lev 23.  I am referring to the practice of referring to Friday as the day of preparation.

Comment: @Ruminator - PLEASE read my posts - I said it was NOT a holy day.  It is simply the name of the day before Sabbath.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I am a tad bit stubborn and will continue to pursuer some kind of documentation of the definition. @holdtotherod has suggested the Josephus has something to say about it.

Comment: Thanks. How do you square that with this?: [Mark 14:12 NASB20] (12) On the first day of Unleavened Bread, when the Passover [lamb] was being sacrificed, His disciples said to Him, "Where do You want us to go and prepare for You to eat the Passover?"

Comment: @Ruminator - there is a long-standing debate about the timing/chronology of the Gospel accounts and that question has many sides.  suffice to say here that because the Passover would normally have begun on Friday, Jesus would not have been available so they began a night early - but this is contested.

Comment: There is also a misconception about the timing of the events that took place after the Sabbath. The verse in Matthew 28 does not say Jesus was raised early on the morning, rather it says that was when Mary went to the tomb! The chronology of the angel rolling away the stone most likely happened during the night...quite possibly after dusk on the Sabbath. My reasoning behind this is the Genesis description of "the evening and the morning" for each day of creation.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a prior answer, παρασκευή ("preparation") is always a reference to Friday when discussing days of the week. I don't believe Matthew is referring to a specific holiday, he's just saying it was the day after Friday. Why the chief priests and Pharisees were doing this on the Sabbath is another question.

So the short answer would be, this is a reference to the normal weekly occurrence of Friday, rather than to an annual holiday.

**Longer answer--Nisan dates**

There is a debate as to whether the crucifixion took place on 14 Nisan (per John) or 15 Nisan (the most common reading the synoptics) on the Jewish calendar. Much ink has been spilled trying to resolve this chronology. My own assessment of the data, found [here](https://youtu.be/WZAc7aNabj4), suggests only the 14 Nisan date is consistent with the lunar cycles during the tenure of Pilate, and so John’s chronology is to be preferred.

For a very helpful table of the relevant lunar cycles, the use of the word παρασκευή, and what is or is not meant by "a High Day" (John's parallel passion account), see [here](https://byustudies.byu.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/51.3BlumellWaymentWhenWas.pdf).

Why is the 14th a better fit with the lunar cycles? Assuming the Jews got their new moons right, the only year during which 15 Nisan fell on a Friday while Pilate was in office was in AD 27. 14 Nisan fell on a Friday in both AD 30 & AD 33.

Almost all chronologists agree that AD 27 is too early a date for the crucifixion, no matter how many circles we run around what is meant by John the Baptist beginning his ministry in the 15th year of Tiberius. If the Jewish calendar was correctly calculated (a fair assumption considering how important their calendar was to them), that leaves only AD 30 & AD 33 as plausible dates. In both cases, the date of the crucifixion would be 14 Nisan.

That would mean, on the Julian calendar, Matthew is referring to either Friday April 7, AD 30 or Friday April 3, AD 33. My thoughts as to which date is more likely are shared [here](https://youtu.be/WZAc7aNabj4).

---

**Addendum re additional question asked**

*Also, does Matthew clarify "the next day" with "which followed the Day of Preparation" to indicate that he meant the "day" part of the "evening and morning" of the day that Jesus was buried, which was Nisan 14/Pesach, when one would eat the meal?*

The short answer would be that when Matthew says "the next day" he is probably referring to the Sabbath, presumably 15 Nisan.

To put it more specifically, though, it would be from sundown on what we call Friday til sundown on what we call Saturday. The events Matthew describes occurred between those two sundowns. It could have been on what we would call Friday night or what we would call Saturday early morning, morning, or afternoon. Either would be 15 Nisan.

Since the chief priests and Pharisees would have been eating the feast at the beginning (sundown) of 15 Nisan, it seems more likely that they went to see Pilate the following morning, during the daylight portion of 15 Nisan.

Comment: PS you asked about Gregorian dates as well--for AD 30 or AD 33 it's just a 2 day discrepancy between Julian & Gregorian, so April 7, AD 30 Julian = April 5, AD 30 Gregorian.  And April 3, AD 33 Julian = April 1, AD 33 Gregorian.

Comment: Is "the day of preparation" described in Leviticus 23?

Comment: @Ruminator to the best of my knowledge, it is not

Comment: So where is it described?

Comment: Is there anywhere in sacred scripture that the day of preparation is explained? I literally have no idea what this mysterious feast day is.

Comment: @Ruminator for a close, contemporary source, Josephus is probably your best best--see Antiquities 16, 6, 2. He also uses the term to refer to Friday, not to an annual holiday. BibleHub has a nice summary of usage & meaning of παρασκευή (Strong's 3904) here: https://biblehub.com/greek/3904.htm - as near as I can tell, the scriptural authors took it as a given that the audience knew what the day of preparation was, they didn't bother to describe it. I don't think it is a feast, it's just Friday

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it. The NT authors use the term as if it means something but no Jew for 2000 years know anything about such a thing; ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122741/discussion-between-hold-to-the-rod-and-ruminator).

Comment: @Ruminator asks "*Is there anywhere in sacred scripture that the day of preparation is explained?*".  The closest thing is [Exodus 16:23](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/exo/16/23/s_66023) and surrounding verses. ¶ "*this mysterious feast day*" is neither mysterious nor a feast.  It's simply the time when everyone is preparing for the next day (e.g. like daytime of December 24 in modern society is when everyone prepares for Xmas day).

Comment: @RayButterworth Thanks.

Comment: @Ruminator says "*no Jew for 2000 years know anything about such a thing*". A few years ago I stayed with a Jewish friend for a week. He had warned me that one day in the middle I'd be on my own because of Yom Kippur, when he fasted and abstained from physical activity. The fast begins at sunset, and several times during the daytime before it, he referred to "The Preparation", which I heard with capital letters. I wasn't sure what it meant, perhaps a ceremony, but it turned out that he was simply referring to eating an extra large meal just before sunset *in preparation* for 25 hours without.

Comment: Fortunately, the Jewish Encyclopedia documents things. However, I couldn't find anything on it on that site. I'm pretty sure that means it never existed and that was just as you say, "getting the tank filled."

Answer (score 1):

**Overview**
As the literal translation shows, the text simply says *after the preparation*:

> And on the morrow that is after the preparation, were gathered together the chief priests, and the Pharisees, unto Pilate, (Matthew 27:62 YLT)

> τῇ δὲ ἐπαύριον ἥτις ἐστὶν **μετὰ τὴν παρασκευήν** συνήχθησαν οἱ ἀρχιερεῖς καὶ οἱ Φαρισαῖοι πρὸς Πιλᾶτον

Preparation **day** is an interpretation; the text simply says, the preparation, and as the other answers show, there is no Biblical "Day of Preparation." However, there are certain legal days for which preparation **before** the required day is either specifically required or logically implied. For example, Tabernacles requires living in booths for 7-days and begins with a day on which work is prohibited. So in order to observe Tabernacles, one's booth must be prepared in advance of the 7-days, and it would be logical to speak of "preparation" during the time leading up to Tabernacles.

With that in mind, here are the potential "preparations" during the time which Jesus was executed:

```
Weekly Sabbath - no work is permitted
Feast of Unleavened Bread - all leaven must be removed before
Feast of First Fruits - the barley must be harvested
```

**Sabbath**
The most likely candidate is preparation for the weekly Sabbath. Since work and shopping were prohibited on the Sabbath, one would need to prepare to observe it. For example during the Exodus the Israelites would gather twice as much manna as on the other days:

> On the sixth day, when they prepare what they bring in, it will be twice as much as they gather daily. (Exodus 16:5 ESV)

Additionally, the Resurrection is immediately after the Sabbath and the sequence of preparation, Sabbath, and Resurrection is commonly accepted. This sequence is not without problems. First, it does not equal the three days and three nights which Jonah spent in the belly of the great fish (cf. [Matthew 12:38-41](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2012%3A38-41&version=ESV)). Second, it means the Pharisees went to Pilate on the Sabbath Day. This is possible, but given what the Gospel says about Pharisees and the Sabbath, it seems unlikely they would do this on the Sabbath.

**Feast of Unleavened Bread**
In addition to eating unleavened bread for 7-days, the Israelites were commanded to remove all leaven from their homes:

> Seven days you shall eat unleavened bread. On the first day you shall remove leaven out of your houses, for if anyone eats what is leavened, from the first day until the seventh day, that person shall be cut off from Israel. (Exodus 12:15; also [13:7 and Deuteronomy 16:4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2013%3A7%3B%20Deuteronomy%2016%3A4&version=ESV)))

The command states to remove the leaven on the first day, but like Tabernacles, the first day is a day of no work and logically the removal of leaven would be done before the first day. In fact, the instruction in Deuteronomy is specific: no leaven must be in their presence for 7-days. Modern observation begins with "deep" cleaning of the house weeks before the Passover and embellishes the Passover observance by adding *[Bedikat Hametz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedikas_chametz)* on the evening before Passover.<sup>`1`</sup>

If by preparation Matthew meant Bedikat Hametz, or a similar extra-Biblical observation, then the sequence would be preparation-Unleavened Bread-Sabbath. This also raises questions but does better align with Jesus' three days/three nights prediction. Additionally, if by "the preparation" Matthew was referring to preparation for Unleavened Bread, it is possible the meaning should not be limited to a single day but the entire process of removing leaven which was finished on a certain day, but may have lasted several days.

**Feast of First Fruits**
The Feast of First Fruits falls on the day after the Sabbath which follows the Passover:

> <sup>9</sup> And the LORD spoke to Moses, saying, <sup>10</sup> “Speak to the people of Israel and say to them, When you come into the land that I give you and reap its harvest, you shall bring the sheaf of the firstfruits of your harvest to the priest, <sup>11</sup> and he shall wave the sheaf before the LORD, so that you may be accepted. On the day after the Sabbath the priest shall wave it. <sup>12</sup> And on the day when you wave the sheaf, you shall offer a male lamb a year old without blemish as a burnt offering to the LORD. <sup>13</sup> And the grain offering with it shall be two tenths of an ephah of fine flour mixed with oil, a food offering to the LORD with a pleasing aroma, and the drink offering with it shall be of wine, a fourth of a hin. <sup>14</sup> And you shall eat neither bread nor grain parched or fresh until this same day, until you have brought the offering of your God: it is a statute forever throughout your generations in all your dwellings. (Leviticus 23)

If one considers gathering the items needed to observe this day as work and if they are not gathered on the actual day of First Fruits, then, like the weekly Sabbath preparation before the day would be necessary. While this would seem to be speaking of the day immediately before the Sabbath, the first day of Unleavened Bread is a day of no work, and, depending on the actual custom of observance, it is possible preparation would occur 2-days before the weekly Sabbath: preparation, 1<sup>st</sup> day of Unleavened Bread, weekly Sabbath, Resurrection. This sequence best fits the Jonah prediction. Regardless of the exact sequence, the Resurrection occurred on the Day of First Fruits.

**Conclusion**
"Preparation" as used by Matthew is a colloquial term whose precise meaning is uncertain.  The issue is compounded by the custom of referring to the 8-days of Passover and Unleavened Bread by a single name: Unleavened Bread (cf. [Matthew 26:17; Mark 14:12; Luke 22:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2026%3A17%3B%20Mark%2014%3A12%3B%20Luke%2022%3A7&version=ESV)) and/or Passover (cf. Luke 22:1). So even if there were a Biblical "Day of Preparation," there is no way to say it was used in a strict Biblical sense.

---

<sub>1. Kevin Howard and Marvin Rosenthal, *The Feasts of the Lord*, Thomas Nelson Inc., 1997, p. 67</sub>

Comment: It does seem that in the chaos of all these variables it is impossible to speak of dates with much certainty. In fact, the same could be said of all the scriptures. In my view, everything in the scriptures is pure double-speak!

Comment: @Ruminator Well it is reasonably certain the Resurrection occurred immediately following the Sabbath and if First Fruits was observed according to the literal instructions, that was also the day of the Resurrection. Therefore, we can say with certainty, the LORD commanded the Day of Resurrection to be the Day First Fruits was supposed to be observed.

Comment: Okay, but that seems rather tangential to what you are pursuing, no?

Comment: I just added that to the question you asked. When addressing issues for which there is no certain answer, I think it is important to include that which is not in dispute. If it is a distraction I can remove it.

Comment: No, more is better when it comes to data.

Answer (score 0):

If the Greek word for "preparation" means Friday (and it does), then why do we not let that settle the argument?  Had that word been translated as "Friday," we would not even talk about some special holy day of preparation that does not exist in the Bible.  It seems we are trying to make the Bible fit a modern understanding of "after three days," "on the third day," and "three days and three nights" instead of trying to understand it from the viewpoint of the Jews/Israelites that lived during and before that time.  Why not let the Bible just be the truth?  The fact is that Jesus died for our sins, He was buried, and He rose from the grave--all according to Scripture!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, “the day of preparation” is not a holy day, in the sense, it is not a rest day, that is, work is not prohibited.

Part of the confusion could be dispelled if we would understand how the NT writers described how the contemporary Jews reckoned the Passover and the days of Unleavened Bread (UB). These are provided in the following verses:

**Passover and the Feast of UB Interchanged**

The New Testament uses Passover and the UB **interchangeably**. Sometimes it calls the entire 8 days (1 day Passover + 7 days UB) as Passover and sometimes the Feast of UB and sometimes both, as in Mark 14:1.

> “And on the **first day of the Feast of Unleavened Bread**, the
> disciples came to Jesus, saying to Him, Where do you desire we should
> prepare for You to **eat the Passover**?” (Matt 26:17).

Here Matthew clubs together both the Passover on Nissan 14 and the 7 days of UB that begins on Nissan 15, the immediate next day. So, here we see, the 1+7=8 days are called UB!

> “And on the **first day of the Unleavened Bread**, when they **killed
> the Passover**” (Mar 14:12).

Again we see Mark doing the same, that is, the 1 (Passover day) +7 (UB days) = 8 days are called UB.

> “And **the Feast of Unleavened Bread, BEING CALLED Passover**, drew
> near” (Luke 22:1).

Here, Luke says that the 1 (Passover day) + 7 (UB days) = 8 days, the entire 8 days are also called Passover. This is what John calls in John 19:14!

> "And the **day of the Unleavened Bread** came, **ON WHICH the
> Passover** must be killed” (Luke 22:7).

So, Luke is very clear: the entire 1 + 7 = 8 days are called **either** UB days **or** Passover. If we do not understand this, we could end up confusing the terms. But Mark says that sometimes these 8 days are called both (given below).

The **fact** is Passover falls on Nissan 14th and the very next day, Nissan 15th, comes the first day of the UB. So the 1 day Passover + 7 days UB are considered to be, for practical purposes, ONE feast. Sometimes, they call it Passover, sometimes the UB and sometimes, both as in Mark 14:1:

“And it was the **Passover, and (the Feast) of Unleavened (Bread)** after two days”.

So, we see:

- Nissan 14 – Passover, a **working** day;
- **Nissan 15 – first day of UB**; an annual Sabbath (a high day); **no work**;
- Nissan 16 – second day of UB; a working day;
- Nissan 17 – third day of UB; a working day;
- Nissan 18 – fourth day of UB; a working day;
- Nissan 19 – fifth day of UB; a working day;
- Nissan 20 – sixth day of UB; a working day;
- **Nissan 21 – seventh day of UB**; an annual Sabbath (a high day); **no work**.

[Since UB covers 7 days, the Saturday Sabbath can fall on any day and that day will be a Sabbath rest “according to the commandment” and no work should be done. The next Sunday morning is the Wave Sheaf offering]

Since Passover (Nissan 14) was a working day that immediately preceded the UB and the first day of UB (Nissan 15) was an annual Sabbath on which no work was to be done, Passover day came to be regarded as “the day of Preparation”.

Jesus, as a devout Jew who esteemed and obeyed God’s laws and commandments (but not all the Jewish traditions), observed all the feast days.

- Nissan 14 – Jesus ate the Passover at the evening (Tuesday evening);
- Nissan 14 – Jesus, as “our Passover Lamb” (1 Cor 5:7) was sacrificed during the day (Wednesday day time). It is a working day. At evening Jesus was buried in a hurry. Preparation day of UB;
- Nissan 15 – first day of UB, an annual Sabbath (Thursday day time). “The next day after the day of preparation” the chief priests and the Pharisees came to Pilate. It was well within “a Sabbath day’s journey” (Acts 1:12). So they thought they didn’t break Sabbath according to their tradition.

But they went and secured the sepulcher on the high Sabbath. No wonder, Jesus criticized them for keeping the Sabbath according to their convenience (Luke 14:5).

All these happened during the day time.

**Conclusion**

Since we have seen clearly that 1 Passover day + 7 days of UB = 8 days is interchangeably called either UB feast or Passover or both, we can understand the following verses thus:

> Matthew 27:62 – “And on the morrow (Nissan 15 UB day time), which is
> after the Preparation (Nissan 14 Passover), the chief priests and the
> Pharisees were assembled to Pilate”.

> Mark 15:42 – “And it becoming evening already, since it was the
> preparation (Nissan 14 Passover day ending), that is, the day before
> Sabbath (Nissan 15 UB)”.

> Luke 23:54 – “And it was Preparation Day (Nissan 14 Passover day
> ending), and a sabbath (Nissan 15 UB) was coming on”.

> John 19:14 – “And it was the Preparation (Nissan 14 Passover day) **of
> the Passover (1 day + 7 days = 8 days known as the Passover as per
> Luke 22:1)**, and about the sixth hour. And he said to the Jews,
> Behold, your King!”

> John 19:31 – “Then, since it was Preparation (Nissan 14 Passover day
> ending), that the bodies not remain on the cross on the Sabbath
> (Nissan 15 UB), for **great was the day of that Sabbath**, the Jews
> asked Pilate that their legs might be broken and they be taken away”.

> John 19:42 – “There, then, because of the Preparation (Nissan 14
> Passover day ending) of the Jews, because the tomb was near, they put
> Jesus”.